# File names error while uploading FTP VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I have a simple program that gets all files in a directory (jpg images) and uploads them to my FTP.

**My problem is the filenames**, I can't upload the images with the full path+filename.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
    Dim filearray() As String
    filearray = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\ImagesTemp")
    For Each File In filearray     
        My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(File, "ftp://trololweb.es/ImagenesRedimensionadas", "user", "pass", True, 500, FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)
        MessageBox.Show(File)
    Next
End Sub
```

This is what gives me the filename error, so i tried with:

```
    namefile= Path.GetNameFile(filearray(file))
```

but when i try to run it, instead of giving me the filename, it gives me an File not Found exception ( it tries to look for the file in the `/bin/debug folder`, it has nothing to do with `c:\ImagesTemp`, so i have no clue why it does that, i have used it previously in a ListView and it worked fine ).

Next i tried to substring it :

```
namefile=File.Substring(13)
```

But i still get for example: `C:\Big_image.jpg` instead of `C:\ImagesTemp\Big_image.jpg`, so another file not found exception.

I'm lost now, I know there is probably a dumb mistake out there but I can't seem to find it. If you guys could show me the light, I would appreciate it so much.

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you.

**UPDATE**

Ok , so with the code provided in the answer I managed to fix the C:\ part while using substring . The problem now it's a System File not Found Exception , it still looks for the image in the bin/Debug/ folder of VS (haven't compiled it yet ) . Code is looking like this :

```
Dim filearray() As String
    filearray = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\ImagesTemp")


    For Each f As String In filearray
        Debug.WriteLine(f)
        filenom = f.Substring(14)
        Debug.WriteLine(filenom)
        My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(filenom, "ftp://web.es/ImagenesRedimensionadas", "user", "pass", True, 500, FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)
        MessageBox.Show(filenom)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Each **File** In filearray

This is your problem, File is a Class in System.IO

Change to something else like

> For Each **_file** In filearray

...And as it is another fine example for it, turn on **Option Strict**

this works as expected

```
Dim filearray() As String
filearray = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Images")
For Each _f As String In filearray
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(_f, "ftp://trololweb.es/ImagenesRedimensionadas/" & IO.Path.GetFileName(_f), "user", "pass", True, 50, FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)
    MessageBox.Show(_f)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll be looking for sure how to turn Option Strict on and will learn how to work around it . But , meanwhile i tried with your code  and substring  , but I'm still getting C:\imagename.jpg instead of only imagename.jpg .

Comment: I updated the code, I forgot that the filename needs to be added to the ftp server. Just tried and works without problems. 
On what line are you getting your exception?

Comment: Oh that totally worked!! I was thinking about this , like how can I tell that sentece the filename with path so it can find it and at the same time without path so I could get the name right . Thank you very much ! Tried to upvote you but seems I'm too much of a new member for this . You made my day , thank you.

Comment: I assume you mean the green tick at the left of your answer ? If not , plz let me know !